# get assembly by class name

Tags: c#, reflection

Is there any way to get the assembly that contains a class with name `TestClass`?
I just know the class name, so I can't create an instance of that. And

```
Type objectType = assembly.GetType("TestClass");
```

didn't work for me.

Comment: Iterating over all referenced assemblies would be your only option, but it would also easily result in duplicates. But I don't quite believe that's all information you have, so you should try and be more explicit about your reasoning for your question.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From the `Type objectType` in the question, I assume you are *actually* after the type by name (not the assembly); so *assuming* the assembly is loaded and the type name is unique, LINQ may help:

```
Type objectType = (from asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                   from type in asm.GetTypes()
                   where type.IsClass && type.Name == "TestClass"
                   select type).Single();
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);
```

However, it may be better to work with the assembly-qualified name instead of the type name.

Comment: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

Comment: @Soonts - sounds like perhaps there is a dependency in an assembly that is missing?

Answer (score 38):

```
Assembly asm = typeof(TestClass).Assembly;
```

will get you the assembly as long as it is referenced. Otherwise, you would have to use a fully qualified name:

```
Assembly asm = null;
Type type = Type.GetType("TestNamespace.TestClass, ConsoleApplication1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");
if (type != null)
{
    asm = type.Assembly;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually knowledge of classname is enough in most scenarios. MSDN says - If the type is in the currently executing assembly or in Mscorlib.dll, it is sufficient to supply the type name qualified by its namespace.

```
Type neededType = Type.GetType("TestClass"); //or typeof(TestClass) 
Assembly a = neededType.Assembly;
```

In case you dont know the assembly containing type (though i cant imagine why) -

```
Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
Asssembly result = assemblies.FirstOrDefault(a=>a.GetType("TestClass",false)!=null);
```

The only restriction - assembly containing TestClass should have been already loaded at the moment of calling such code.

Hope this'll help. :)

Answer (score 5):

Marc's answer is really good, but since it was too slow (I'm using that method often), I decided to go with a different approach:

```
    private static Dictionary<string, Type> types;
    private static readonly object GeneralLock = new object();

    public static Type FindType(string typeName)
    {
        if (types == null)
        {
            lock (GeneralLock)
            {
                if (types == null)
                {
                    types = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
                    var appAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
                    foreach (var appAssembly in appAssemblies)
                    {
                        foreach (var type in appAssembly.GetTypes())
                            if (!types.ContainsKey(type.Name))
                                types.Add(type.Name, type);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return types[typeName];
    }
```

You can handle the name clash the way you want, but in this example I decided to just ignore the subsequent ones.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to store the `Type`'s `FullName` and the `Assembly`'s `Name` only:

```
var typeFullName = myType.FullName; // Namespace.Name ie. "Core.MyObj"
var assemblyName = myType.Assembly.GetName().Name; // ie. "Core"
```

*Usually the Assembly Name and the Namespace are the same, but not always.*

Then you can do this:

```
var typeName = $"{t.FullName}, {t.Assembly.GetName().Name}"; // "Core.MyObj, Core"
```

or even write an extension method:

```
public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static string FullNameAndAssembly(this Type type)
    {
        return $"{type.FullName}, {type.Assembly.GetName().Name}";
    }
}
```

This will always work even when changing the `Assembly` version:

```
Type myObjType = Type.GetType("Core.MyObj, Core");
```

I found that storing the `Assembly`'s `FullName` won't work if the `Assembly`'s version changes.

Example of `Assembly.FullName`:

```
Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

This won't work and you will get `null`:

```
Type.GetType(
    "Core.MyObj, Core, Version=1.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
);
```