# Get assembly or dll by class name or type C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I tried to find how I can find dll or assembly by type that I need to use (by C#).

I'd like to make method that can type some thing like "#include System.IO;" when it see in text of this class file variable with type "Path".
So generally I want to get all assemblies which is on the computer. I understand that there is some General Assembly Cache but I don't really understand how to use it in this case.
As I understand method GetType from Assemble can work, but I can't find all assemblies to use this method to them.

Methods using AppDomain is useless because using assemblies only included in this solution [How to Load an Assembly to AppDomain with all references recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658498/how-to-load-assembly-to-appdomain-with-all-references-recursively), [get assembly by class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657424/get-assembly-by-class-name).

To be more specific it's some custom realization of Visual Studio method Resolve 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNns9.png

As I understand that I should find method which is invoked by VS Tools->Customize->Commands->Click Context menu and choose Editor Context Menus|Code Window|Resolve.

Sorry for this simple question but for me it is important.

Comment: Why would you want to do this, what does this achieve? You could use the current application domain (see AppDomain), get the directory that the application is running from, and get all program files in the directory.

Comment: Loading assembly from GAC: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2279362/4544845

Comment: I don't think you want something like the Visual Studio "resolve" because that only works with assemblies that are referenced by the project.

Comment: This sounds like you are trying to get some editor (your own or Visual Studio maybe) to search your entire drive to find out what include needs to be added when you type in a partial path name. Would that be a correct description of your question? Sorry, but imgur is blocked where I'm at so I can't see your image.

Comment: Steve, you are quite right. I understand that I should find method which invoke VS it's commands via customize (Tools->Customize->Commands->Click Context menu and choose Editor Context Menus|Code Window|Resolve.

Comment: Moby's answer below extended to searching all available locations would be sufficient to find the information you are looking for.  As others have said, the visual studio resolve event is only going to look at assemblies already loaded in your project.  The biggest issue is that just finding the assembly and adding the statement isn't going to produce code that will compile as you now have to add a reference to to the assembly that you found, plus any dependencies that assembly has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://mobydisk.com/softdev/techinfo/dotnetexceptions.html) is a tool that scans all the assemblies on the system and searches through all the classes in those assemblies, looking for certain types.  The tool only searches the .NET SDK directories, not the GAC.  If you modify the program to also search the %systemroot%\assembly folder, then you should get classes that are in the GAC as well.

The code is a long to paste into the answer, but the general idea is this:

1. Find all the .NET DLL files
2. Call Assembly.LoadFrom() or Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad() on each DLL
3. Call GetExportedTypes() to get the list of types
4. Loop through there to find the class you are interested in.

Here is a relevant code excerpt that might help.  It will look for the class "File" in the namespace "System.IO" without any prior knowledge of what DLL that might be in.

```
string[] assemblyPaths = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\", "*.dll", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (string assemblyPath in assemblyPaths)
{
   Assembly assembly = null;
   assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);

   // Go through all the types in it
   foreach (Type t in assembly.GetExportedTypes())
   {
       // Publically creatable exception?
       if (t.IsPublic && t.Name == "File" && t.Namespace == "System.IO")
       {
           // The type "t" is the type you are looking for
       }
   }
}
```

The linked project is a bit smarter and not so oversimplified.  But that's the general idea.